# Print AutoFilter Array to Immediate Window

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I'm interested in printing an AutoFilter array to the Immediate Window. I can capture this manually by recording a macro while filtering a column, as seen below:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AF$1191").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "3", "4", "5"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What result are you expecting to see?

Comment: @QHarr Ideally, I would like to print the piece of code I included verbatim to the Immediate Window.

Comment: I don't think you can print it as is to the immediate. It would need to be a string.

Comment: @QHarr any thoughts on how to capture this existing Autofilter array as a string?

Comment: Not without enclosing it between " " and assigning to a variable. Doubling up on the inner "" and debug.print the variable.

Comment: I am wondering if i am misunderstanding you. Do you mean something like this? https://pastebin.com/905vzwfC

Comment: @QHarr let me rephrase this. how would you go about printing this array as a single string to a worksheet cell? If I could do this, I could then figure out the Immediate Window piece. Does this make sense?

Comment: Do you mean the filtered range address? The pastebin link shows how to print the string as is coded.

Comment: @QHarr I'm trying to capture the all the filter details for a column

Comment: Can you give an example expected output?

Comment: @QHarr I'm literally trying to capture the code sample I provided as a string or multiple strings.  My end goal is to have a script that can capture the filter settings for each column in a worksheet. Does this make sense?

Comment: Did you see the pastebin link i gave? https://pastebin.com/905vzwfC

Comment: yes. this doesn't address how to capture pre-existing filter settings as a string.

Comment: Not as a string but the following captures the settings: https://pastebin.com/F2XxD47M   Might be a starting point.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have figured it out. I need to update this to handle all [operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlautofilteroperator-enumeration-excel), but this is what I have so far.

```
Sub PrintFilters()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    Dim wsn As String
    wsn = ws.Name

    Dim LastCol As Integer
    LastCol = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    Dim AllCrit As Variant
    Dim CritVar As Variant
    Dim CritString As String

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To LastCol

    On Error Resume Next

    With ws.AutoFilter.Filters(i)

        Select Case .Operator

            Case Is = 7 'xlFilterValues
                For Each CritVar In .Criteria1
                    AllCrit = AllCrit & Chr(44) & Chr(34) & Mid(CritVar, 2) & Chr(34)
                    CritString = AllCrit
                    CritString = Replace(CritString, Chr(44), "", 1, 1)
                Next
                Debug.Print "ThisWorkBook.Sheets(" & Chr(34) & wsn & Chr(34) & Chr(41) & ".UsedRange.Autofilter Field:=" & i & Chr(44) & "Criteria1:=Array(" & CritString & ")," & "Operator:=xlFilterValues"

            Case Is = 2 'xlOr
                Debug.Print "ThisWorkBook.Sheets(" & Chr(34) & wsn & Chr(34) & Chr(41) & ".UsedRange.Autofilter Field:=" & i & Chr(44) & "Criteria1:=" & Chr(34) & Mid(.Criteria1, 2) & Chr(34) & Chr(44) & "Operator:=xlOr" & Chr(44) & ("Criteria2:=" & Chr(34) & Mid(.Criteria2, 2)) & Chr(34)

            Case Is = 0, 1 'other cases / xlAnd
                Debug.Print "ThisWorkBook.Sheets(" & Chr(34) & wsn & Chr(34) & Chr(41) & ".UsedRange.Autofilter Field:=" & i & Chr(44) & "Criteria1:=" & Chr(34) & Mid(.Criteria1, 1) & Chr(34)

        End Select

    End With

    AllCrit = Nothing
    Next i

End Sub
```