# Save Filter by Color value as variable

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

With the macro recorder on, I was able to capture the following code when filtering a range by color. Once this filter is set, is it possible capture the RGB values as a variable?

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AF$1191").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=RGB(255 _
        , 199, 206), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
```

Comment: The codes show rgb values are already captured.

Comment: you're correct. I'm asking if it's possible to store these RGB values as their own variable. This way I can recall these values later.

Comment: If you export the property `interior.color` of a cell into a string, it automatically gets converted to a working number you can then recall.

Comment: @FernandoJ.Rivera good suggestion. Any thoughts on how to go about doing that in this context? Ideally I’d like to put this string back into a filter later (if that makes sense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will filter your table based on the colour of ActiveCell. If this was my file, I'd have a working cell outside of my table, say for example `AH1`, and then I'd change the code to have `str=range("AH1").interior.color`, that way it will filter your table based on `AH1`'s colour.

```
Sub testy()
Dim str As String

str = ActiveCell.Interior.Color

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AF$1191").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=str, Operator:=xlFilterCellColor

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for this. The issue with this is that I won't know what the filter color is. My goal is to capture the filtered color value set by a user. This being the case, I'll never know what the color is going to be.

Comment: ah, I think I have it. If the used range is filtered based on a color, I can just capture the interior color of any cell in that colored column.

Comment: There is no way to call a macro directly when the user changes a column filter. I recommend handling the filtering inside your macro when a user clicks on a button, and then it filters based on a helper cell's colour (that is, do not let the user directly filter the data in the sheet but pop a userform from where they can filter the column).

Comment: Thanks. For some context, I'm working on a script that prints all filter settings to the Immediate Window (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47512343/print-autofilter-array-to-immediate-window?noredirect=1#comment81985537_47512343), and I was stuck on this particular piece. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction